# If the dependent variable in an ARDL model is a growth rate, must predictors also be growth rates?

Tags: data-transformation, ardl

If I use growth rate of Y as the dependent variable in an ARDL model, do predictors need to be converted into growth rates, too?

Answer (score 0):

From the statistical perspective, there is no such requirement. From the subject-matter perspective, such a requirement may or may not make sense.